# why cannot save qr code image into folder in server?

Tags: php

I did this in localhost XAMPP and it works well. But after I upload into server, it doesn't save QR image into folder in server but only save into database. So, can anyone point me the problem? Once solved it I'll move forward. Thanks!

```
$text = "PRODUCT ID 23456";
$qrImgName = "QRQ".rand();
$qrs = $qrImgName.".png";



 //file path
$file = "qrcode/gbrqrcode/$qrImgName.png";

//other parameters
$ecc = 'H';
$pixel_size = 20;
$frame_size = 5;

// Generates QR Code and Save as PNG
QRcode::png($text, $file, $ecc, $pixel_size, $frame_size);
```

Comment: Check permission for ``qrcode/gbrqrcode`` in your server. it should have read and write permission.

Comment: permissions : drwxr-xr-x

Comment: Try to set 777(rwxrwxrwx) to the folder. It should be a permission issue.